# Empty body when posting data using fetch()

Tags: javascript, api, asp.net-web-api

Here is my controller which is getting called, but value is always ends up null:

```
 public void Post([FromBody]string value) {
 }
```

This is how it's being called:

```
function () {
    var data = {
        'sku': $('#radioProduct').val(),
        'qty': $('#productQty').val()
    }
    return fetch('/api/Default', {
         method: 'post',
         headers: {
              'content-type': 'application/json'
         },
         body: JSON.stringify(data)
         }).then(function (res) {
             return res.json();
         }).then(function (data) {
             return data.orderID; // Use the same key name for order ID on the client and server
         });
   }
});
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?  The API does get called but the body is empty.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Take a look at the network panel of your browser developer tools to identify what actually got sent, so you can distinguish between client- and server-side problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `null` because you're POSTing the following JSON:

```
{
    "sku": "sku's value",
    "qty": 1
}
```

but your controller is expecting a `string`. By the fact you've specified `application/json` as the `Content-Type`, what you need to do instead is have a class that models the two values you're expecting to receive:

```
public class ProductInfo
{
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
}
```

Without doing that, the model binder doesn't know how to associate the values for `sku` and `qty` to anything, and so you get `null`.

Finally, change your action to:

```
public void Post([FromBody]ProductInfo productInfo)
```

Model binding is handled entirely by convention, which means associating property names, or primitive values, with JSON or other data you send to a controller.